# Request.Headers to read GET URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers, response-headers

I have some code,

```
    if (Request.Headers["User-Agent"] == "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT; MS Search 6.0 Robot)")
    {
        this.Response.Redirect("/_windows/default.aspx?" + qp.ToString());
    }
    else if(Request.Headers["GET"].Contains("SignOut.aspx") ) {
        this.Response.Redirect("/_layouts/signout.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        this.Response.Redirect("/_trust/default.aspx?trust=ADFS%20DEV&" + qp.ToString());
    }
```

The problem is that my `else if` does not work because `Request.Headers` can not read the "GET", per Microsoft [http://msdn.microsoft.com/](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers(v=vs.110).aspx). I want to know when the GET url contains SignOut.aspx, is there a way for me to read that part of the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [HttpRequest.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url(v=vs.110).aspx), which you can access from the Request object via Request.Url:

```
...
else if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("SignOut.aspx"))
{
    //Whatever
}
...
```

Furthermore, you might want to look more into what the framework offers for handing requests - you're doing things the hard way and re-inventing the wheel. Consider using

```
Request.UserAgent
```

instead of

```
Request.Headers["User-Agent"]
```